# Joomla 3 client side checkbox group validation

Tags: checkbox, joomla

I'm trying to use Joomla's (version 3.4.3) built in form validator: `JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidator');`

I'm trying to apply it for a dynamically generated form. It works fine for dropdown menus and textfields. But when (lets say) I have a group of 4 checkboxes and I want the user to select at least 1 of the 4 then I ran into a problem... The site asks the user to select ALL 4 checkboxes.
Here is the generated HTML code:

```
<label title="Checked out?" class="hasTooltip required" for="jform_checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473" id="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473-lbl">Checked out? <span class="star">*</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473[]" id="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473" value="Yes" class="required" aria-required="true" required="required"> Yes
<input type="checkbox" name="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473[]" id="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473" value="No" class="required" aria-required="true" required="required"> No
<input type="checkbox" name="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473[]" id="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473" value="maybe" class="required" aria-required="true" required="required"> maybe
<input type="checkbox" name="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473[]" id="checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473" value="of course not" class="required" aria-required="true" required="required"> of course not
```

When I try to submit the form I get these error messages:

> Invalid field:  Checked out?
>   Invalid field:  Checked out?
>   Invalid field:  Checked out?
>   Invalid field:  Checked out?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your input elements has the same id, which is "checked-out_cbv_qwq4-473". id attribute should be unique.

Sample code of fieldset with checkboxes:

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="control-label">
    <label id="mycheckboxes-lbl" for="mycheckboxes" class="required">Checked out?<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <fieldset id="mycheckboxes" class="checkboxes required" required="required" aria-required="true">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" name="myform_checkboxes[]" value="Yes">
                <label for="checkbox_1">Yes</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" name="myform_checkboxes[]" value="No">
                <label for="checkbox_2">No</label>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but if I assign a unique ID for every single checkbox then what should be the ID for the label? I think they should be similar in order to display the "Invalid field: Checked out?" error message. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: "Checked out?" label should belong to fieldset, that fieldset should have your checkboxes, every checkbox should have own label. Fieldset should be required not every checkbox.